# Enable WiFi Drivers for Esp32 board in zephyr

Tags: wifi, esp32, build-system, esp-idf, zephyr-rtos

I am using the wifi sample app from zephyr,
https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/tree/main/samples/net/wifi

I tried to build this application for esp32 board by setting the below lines in CmakeLists.txt file

```
set (BOARD esp32)
set (ZEPHYR_MODULES "[path to zephyr root]/zephyrproject/modules/hal/espressif")
```

When i tried to build using cmake , I got the below errors,

```
warning: MBEDTLS (defined at modules\mbedtls\Kconfig:17) has direct dependencies 0 with value n, but is currently being y-selected by the following symbols:
 - WIFI_ESP32 (defined at drivers/wifi/esp32/Kconfig.esp32:3), with value y, direct dependencies DT_HAS_ESPRESSIF_ESP32_WIFI_ENABLED && !SMP && WIFI (value: y), and select condition DT_HAS_ESPRESSIF_ESP32_WIFI_ENABLED && !SMP && WIFI (value: y)
 - NET_TCP_ISN_RFC6528 (defined at subsys/net/ip/Kconfig:504), with value y, direct dependencies NET_TCP && !NET_RAW_MODE && NETWORKING (value: y), and select condition NET_TCP && !NET_RAW_MODE && NETWORKING (value: y)

warning: MBEDTLS_ECP_C (defined at modules\mbedtls\Kconfig.tls-generic:135) has direct dependencies MBEDTLS_BUILTIN && MBEDTLS_CFG_FILE = "config-tls-generic.h" && MBEDTLS && 0 with value n, but is currently being y-selected by the following symbols:
 - WIFI_ESP32 (defined at drivers/wifi/esp32/Kconfig.esp32:3), with value y, direct dependencies DT_HAS_ESPRESSIF_ESP32_WIFI_ENABLED && !SMP && WIFI (value: y), and select condition DT_HAS_ESPRESSIF_ESP32_WIFI_ENABLED && !SMP && WIFI (value: y)

warning: MBEDTLS_ECDH_C (defined at modules\mbedtls\Kconfig.tls-generic:123) has direct dependencies MBEDTLS_ECP_C && MBEDTLS_BUILTIN && MBEDTLS_CFG_FILE = "config-tls-generic.h" && MBEDTLS && 0 with value n, but is currently being y-selected by the following symbols:
 - WIFI_ESP32 (defined at drivers/wifi/esp32/Kconfig.esp32:3), with value y, direct dependencies DT_HAS_ESPRESSIF_ESP32_WIFI_ENABLED && !SMP && WIFI (value: y), and select condition DT_HAS_ESPRESSIF_ESP32_WIFI_ENABLED && !SMP && WIFI (value: y)

rning: MBEDTLS_ECDSA_C (defined at modules\mbedtls\Kconfig.tls-generic:127) has direct dependencies MBEDTLS_ECP_C && MBEDTLS_BUILTIN && MBEDTLS_CFG_FILE = "config-tls-generic.h" && MBEDTLS && 0 with value n, but is currently being y-selected by the following symbols:
 - WIFI_ESP32 (defined at drivers/wifi/esp32/Kconfig.esp32:3), with value y, direct dependencies DT_HAS_ESPRESSIF_ESP32_WIFI_ENABLED && !SMP && WIFI (value: y), and select condition DT_HAS_ESPRESSIF_ESP32_WIFI_ENABLED && !SMP && WIFI (value: y)

warning: MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_ECDHE_ECDSA_ENABLED (defined at modules\mbedtls\Kconfig.tls-generic:102) has direct dependencies MBEDTLS_ECDH_C && MBEDTLS_ECDSA_C && MBEDTLS_BUILTIN && MBEDTLS_CFG_FILE = "config-tls-generic.h" && MBEDTLS && 0 with value n, but is currently being y-selected by the following symbols:
 - WIFI_ESP32 (defined at drivers/wifi/esp32/Kconfig.esp32:3), with value y, direct dependencies DT_HAS_ESPRESSIF_ESP32_WIFI_ENABLED && !SMP && WIFI (value: y), and select condition DT_HAS_ESPRESSIF_ESP32_WIFI_ENABLED && !SMP && WIFI (value: y)

warning: MBEDTLS_ECP_ALL_ENABLED (defined at modules\mbedtls\Kconfig.tls-generic:143) has direct dependencies MBEDTLS_ECP_C && MBEDTLS_BUILTIN && MBEDTLS_CFG_FILE = "config-tls-generic.h" && MBEDTLS && 0 with value n, but is currently being y-selected by the following symbols:
 - WIFI_ESP32 (defined at drivers/wifi/esp32/Kconfig.esp32:3), with value y, direct dependencies DT_HAS_ESPRESSIF_ESP32_WIFI_ENABLED && !SMP && WIFI (value: y), and select condition DT_HAS_ESPRESSIF_ESP32_WIFI_ENABLED && !SMP && WIFI (value: y)

warning: MBEDTLS_MAC_MD5_ENABLED (defined at modules\mbedtls\Kconfig.tls-generic:309) has direct dependencies MBEDTLS_BUILTIN && MBEDTLS_CFG_FILE = "config-tls-generic.h" && MBEDTLS && 0 with value n, but is currently being y-selected by the following symbols:
 - NET_TCP_ISN_RFC6528 (defined at subsys/net/ip/Kconfig:504), with value y, direct dependencies NET_TCP && !NET_RAW_MODE && NETWORKING (value: y), and select condition NET_TCP && !NET_RAW_MODE && NETWORKING (value: y)

warning: MBEDTLS_MD (defined at modules\mbedtls\Kconfig.tls-generic:361) has direct dependencies MBEDTLS_BUILTIN && MBEDTLS_CFG_FILE = "config-tls-generic.h" && MBEDTLS && 0 with value n, but is currently being y-selected by the following symbols:
 - NET_TCP_ISN_RFC6528 (defined at subsys/net/ip/Kconfig:504), with value y, direct dependencies NET_TCP && !NET_RAW_MODE && NETWORKING (value: y), and select condition NET_TCP && !NET_RAW_MODE && NETWORKING (value: y)

warning: MBEDTLS_ENTROPY_ENABLED (defined at modules\mbedtls\Kconfig.tls-generic:381) has direct dependencies (MBEDTLS_MAC_SHA256_ENABLED || MBEDTLS_MAC_SHA384_ENABLED || MBEDTLS_MAC_SHA512_ENABLED) && MBEDTLS_BUILTIN && MBEDTLS_CFG_FILE = "config-tls-generic.h" && MBEDTLS && 0 with value n, but is currently being y-selected by the following symbols:
 - WIFI_ESP32 (defined at drivers/wifi/esp32/Kconfig.esp32:3), with value y, direct dependencies DT_HAS_ESPRESSIF_ESP32_WIFI_ENABLED && !SMP && WIFI (value: y), and select condition DT_HAS_ESPRESSIF_ESP32_WIFI_ENABLED && !SMP && WIFI (value: y)

error: Aborting due to Kconfig warnings
```

I am new for zephyr. I am not sure whether I am correct in the way i am doing things or not.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and adding a `west.yml` file including the following solved it for me:

```
manifest:
  project
    - name: mbedtls
      path: modules/crypto/mbedtls
```

My tree looks like

```
.
├── applications
├── bootloader
├── modules
├── tools
├── west.yml
└── zephyr
```

The structure is modules/crypto/mbedlts. You have to give zephyr the source for the external module. Meaning adding the path in your west.yml and doing a `west update`.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**